# Django Query with and without comma

Tags: python, django

I have a .csv file with only one column (name) and multiple rows containing strings formatted like:

1. "name, surname"
2. "name surname"

I loop through this file and check if they exist in my database

the only problem is that in my database, everything is formatted like:

1. "name, surname"

so the query without a comma could not be found unless I do something like this:

```
Model.objects.filter(name__search=row["name"])
```

But this takes a very long time to load..

is there any other way?

Comment: Have you tried Replace function on annotated field? You could replace ' ' with ', ' and then query on that annotated field but I don't know if it would be any faster

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with `contains`? See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#contains-1

It may be faster if you do:

```py
Model.objects.filter(name__contains=row["name"])
```

You can also try to use `icontains` if you want to search for case-insensitive text. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#icontains

If none of this alternatives work for you, another option would be to update the `save` method in your `Model` so you can save the data in the format you like and get consistent results there.